# Move element into new position with CSS3 transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I am trying to get a gallery working and I am trying to limit the usage of jQuery in this case. As shown in the following screenshot, I always have 2 items beside each other: http://prntscr.com/2gpi01 . They are set to float left and whenever one is removed or set to display none, another item simply takes its place. This working fine, however I want to add a transition, in order for the new item to move into the old item's place. I have seen this quite often online, that by simply removing an item, another item slides smoothly into its new place. Is this somehow possible with CSS3 transitions?

Comment: ya sure, you could animate margin-left/right e.g.

Comment: I was going to set all of the elements to position absolute and use the 'left' and 'top' property to set the location of each item, which would work similar to margins, but I think I am using too much javascript in that case. Or am I mistaken? :-/

Comment: The important thing is to use CSS3 for the animation. Using javascript to set animation (by e.g adding/removing class for specific elements) won't be an issue regarding performance. Now you shouldn't have to use javascript/jquery to set each item position, only CSS should be enough for that

Comment: Alright, I get the animation part and thanks for the help! However, how exactly do I do this with CSS? I have the bad habit of using position absolute and then setting each item individually, which is a really bad solution, and using floats doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Don't animate `left`, `top` or `margin-left`, `margin-top` but use CSS3 transform's `translate` (X and Y) to have a better performance and smoother results due to hardware acceleration.

Comment: Ah now I understand. Alright, I figured it out thanks to your guy's help :)!  I will give translate a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate `max-width` using `transition`.

On the click event, you need do add class `hidden` to the clicked element.

If you have a markup like this:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><img src="image1" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="image2" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

You can do the animation with the following CSS:

```
ul.gallery li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: max-width 2s;
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.gallery li.hidden {
  max-width: 0;
}

ul.gallery li img {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

Here is a demo:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/pqbkirfl

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using CSS, since CSS won't check if any child element is removed or not!

You can try out the animation using

```
transition: margin-top 2s;
```

This way, the margin-top change for the element will take place in 2 seconds in an animating way.

But to detect the removal of the element you are required to use jQuery!

Since you want the animation to take place only if the element is removed, you can try out adding class or removing a class for the other elements. This way, when the class is added the animation (CSS) will take place and it will animate its property (margin-top).